# Android remove button border

Tags: android, button, styles

i try to remove the boardes of the Button in Andorid.

I know in the design i can change it with:
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"

But how can i change it in the Java code or is there a soulition in the style.xml?

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23175014/5067493) is what you were searching for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Button
   android:background="@drawable/shape"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_parent" />
```

here is shape.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1B5E20" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

just change shape color property like you want..